# How create SWF files from Flash with XML and AS3 in batch?

Tags: python, xml, actionscript-3, flash, sockets

I am currently making `.SWF` file with `Flash`, `XML` and `Action Script 3`. I use data from `XML`(pictures, text), `.FLA` & `AS3` to make the image and text moving in the animation.

```
.FLA > .XML > AS3 > .SWF
```

I have to create file one by one and it took long time to do so. I have many `XML` files that i want to convert into `swf` .So i was thinking to use Python to send command to Flash, like that i can create a batch of videos(swf) without have to use flash(handly) and create it one by one.

But I am looking the option i get and it is not really clear :

There's the

`Python XML Socket`,

`Adobe Air`,

`XMLSocket` .

Can someone help me get the good understanding of the option we have and how can I apply it to my project.

I need a way to communicate with `Python`, `Flash` , `XML`, `AS3` to finnaly create `.swf` files.

Thank you

Comment: Is it necessary that Python be included in the process? If not, you would be able to make a small Flash application that can load XMLs, and create SWFs depending on the contents. Apparently you can use this library to make SWFs at runtime: https://github.com/claus/as3swf

Comment: you could automate swf creation by using the mxmlc compiler that is part of the Flex SDK - you can create batch or ANT scripts to generate the swfs from mxmlc. Heres a basic intro: http://www.ghostwire.com/aspireui/docs/basics/compiling-with-flex-mxmlc

Comment: Python is not necessary, but that's the language i know the best ;), i see in bot of your answer quite good option , but i dont see how to use the .fla in the process !? thanks

Comment: Oh, I see: you want to automatically compile an FLA with different XMLs. I forgot that, since I'm used to compiling pure AS3 with the Flex SDK. It seems that the Flash IDE is the only tool that can compile FLAs, so if it's possible to make Python tell Flash to compile, then you can possibly do that. The only thing is that you would need to load the XML externally, and make Python move and rename each XML to the loading location every time you compile. I'll look to see if I can find examples or something, since I don't know Python myself.

Comment: Nice , with pure AS3 and FLEX SDK , is it possible to animate something ? I am using .FLA for the animation , XML for the data and AS3 to make it work togheter , i am open to see alternative methods :) thanks.

Comment: im the same as puggsoy; so long since i used flash i never even considered FLA format. Its getting more complex, but if it is practical, you can compile the assets from the FLA into a SWC, and then pass that SWC to mxmlc (along with the AS files).

Comment: Animating purely with AS3 is pretty impractical, so what I would do is what Lee suggested: compile the FLA's assets (MovieClips, Sounds, and so forth) into an SWC, which can then be used as a library for your AS3 code. As long as you're pretty good at AS3, you should have no problem adding your MovieClips to the stage and animating them according to the XML. If, however, your animation is on the root stage of your FLA, you will have to convert it into a MovieClip, otherwise it won't be in the SWC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with MTASC and SWFMill for CamCanvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969100/help-with-mtasc-and-swfmill-for-camcanvas)